# React component doesn't get rendered on initial load

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios

I recently started learning React and I'm trying to make my simple app to work.

I have main App component:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
    <BrowserRouter>
     <div>
      <header>
       <h1>Test</h1>
      </header>
    <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><NavLink to="/vehiclemakes">Vehicle Makes</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div className="container">
     <Route path="/vehiclemakes" component={VehicleMakes}/>
    </div>
  </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
 }
}
```

As you can see I'm using routing and in my navbar I have a link to the Vehicle Makes component which should render table with vehicle makes that I get with api call:

```
let vehicleMakes = [];

class VehicleMakes extends React.Component{           
componentDidMount(){
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:15163/api/vehiclemakes`)
    .then((result) => {
     const vehicleMakesData = result;
        vehicleMakes = vehicleMakesData.data.data;
    })
  }

render(){
    return(
        <div>
          <VehicleMakesTable vehicleMakes={vehicleMakes} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

VehicleMakesTable component renders VehicleMakesTableHeader and VehicleMakesTableRow components:

```
class VehicleMakesTable extends React.Component{
render(){
    console.log("table");
    const rows = [];
    this.props.vehicleMakes.forEach((vehicleMake) => {
       rows.push(
        <VehicleMakesTableRow 
            vehicleMake={vehicleMake} 
            key={vehicleMake.id} />
       ); 
    });       
    return(
        <table>
            <thead>
                <VehicleMakesTableHeader />
            </thead>
            <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
        </table>
    );
  }
 }

class VehicleMakesTableHeader extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    );
  }
}

class VehicleMakesTableRow extends React.Component{
render(){
    const vehicleMake = this.props.vehicleMake;
    return(
        <tr>
            <td>{vehicleMake.name}</td>
        </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem that I have is that on initial load when I click Vehicle Makes link in main App component, my table gets rendered but without any rows. So "VehicleMakesTableHeader" component gets rendered but "VehicleMakesTableRow" component doesn't. When I click the link again (second time) then the "VehicleMakesTableRow" component gets rendered also.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, why do I have to click link two times in order for table to be rendered correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
let vehicleMakes = [];

class VehicleMakes extends React.Component{           
  componentDidMount(){
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:15163/api/vehiclemakes`)
    .then((result) => {
       const vehicleMakesData = result;
       vehicleMakes = vehicleMakesData.data.data;
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div>
          <VehicleMakesTable vehicleMakes={vehicleMakes} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You keep `vehicleMakes` as the regular variable. React is not getting notified of any change with this variable and doesn't re-render. That's why you have something like a [react `state`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). Every time `state` changes - react will get notified that state has changed and do re-render. Fix:

```
class VehicleMakes extends React.Component{       
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { vehicleMakes: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:15163/api/vehiclemakes`)
    .then((result) => {
       const vehicleMakes = result.data.data;
       this.setState({ vehicleMakes })
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div>
          <VehicleMakesTable vehicleMakes={this.state.vehicleMakes} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store `vehicleMakes` in state in order to trigger a re-render when you update it in `componentDidMount`:

```
class VehicleMakes ... {
  state = { vehicleMakes: [] }

  ...

    .then(result => this.setState({ vehicleMakes: result.data.data }));

  ...

    <VehicleMakesTable vehicleMakes={this.state.vehicleMakes} />
```